# Warning| Unable to read the license file

Tags: cocoapods

I've followed the rules suggested in the article-https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#license, but I've no luck. A warning is seen when I pod lint the spec -

Unable to read the license file //LICENSE.md for the specname

Installed software versions on my device:
.gem/ruby/2.5.0/
gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/
Xcode-9.2

Here is a line of code added to my podspec file-

s.license          = { :type => 'New BSD', :file => 'LICENSE' }

I've changed the file name to LICENSE.md, but don't see any luck.

Thanks!

Comment: The same problem as you.The LICENSE is in the project,and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for an old app that I wanted to update and the problematic pod was already installed. But, when I tried to build the app it gave me this same error message. Running pod install and pod update did not fix the problem.

I was able to fix this by doing the following:
    1. Delete the line in Podfile for the problematic pod
    2. Run pod install at the command line - this will remove the pod
    3. Reinsert the line for the pod in question in Podfile
    3. Run pod install at the command line again